# Group and sum nested items MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm creating a REST Web Service with Spring Boot and I need group goals by soccer player, to show top scores from following documents:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "adversario": "Dois irmãos",
    "dataRealizacao": "2017-02-03",
    "golsPro": 10,
    "golsContra": 3,
    "jogadoresGols": [
      {
        "jogador": {
          "nome": "Murillo"
        },
        "numeroGols": 6
      },
      {
        "jogador": {
          "nome": "Eduardo"
        },
        "numeroGols": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "adversario": "Amigos Greminho",
    "dataRealizacao": "2017-02-13",
    "golsPro": 17,
    "golsContra": 1,
    "jogadoresGols": [
      {
        "jogador": {
          "nome": "Murillo"
        },
        "numeroGols": 12
      },
      {
        "jogador": {
          "nome": "Eduardo"
        },
        "numeroGols": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to get the following output:

```
[
   {
      "jogador": {
         "nome": "Murillo"
      },
      "totalGols": 18
   },
   {
      "jogador": {
         "nome": "Eduardo"
      },
      "totalGols": 9
   }
]
```

This code doesn't work:

```
@Repository
public class GoleadorRepository {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public GoleadorRepository(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    public List<Goleador> list() {
        SortOperation sortOperation = buildSortOpertation();
        GroupOperation groupOperation = buildGroupOperation();

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                sortOperation,
                groupOperation
        ), Partida.class, Goleador.class).getMappedResults();
    }

    private GroupOperation buildGroupOperation() {
        return group("jogadoresGols.jogador.nome")
                .first("jogadoresGols.jogador.nome").as("jogador")
                .sum("jogadoresGols.jogador.numeroGols").as("totalGols");
    }

    private SortOperation buildSortOpertation() {
        return sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "numeroGols");
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property numeroGols found on br.com.cwidevs.domain.Jogador!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:262) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:222) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.getReferenceFor(TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.java:98) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.getReference(TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.java:93) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation$Operation.getValue(GroupOperation.java:478) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation$Operation.toDBObject(GroupOperation.java:460) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation.toDBObject(GroupOperation.java:408) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationRenderer.toDBObject(AggregationOperationRenderer.java:56) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.toDbObject(Aggregation.java:580) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1566) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1501) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at br.com.cwidevs.repository.GoleadorRepository.list(GoleadorRepository.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.cwidevs.repository.GoleadorRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$56b69c8f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at br.com.cwidevs.repository.GoleadorRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9cb7ef5d.list(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.cwidevs.resource.GoleadorResource.getAll(GoleadorResource.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

> jogador is **Soccer**
>
> numeroGols is **Goals**

Comment: Take a look at this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346329/getting-null-pointer-exception-mongo-aggregation-using-spring-datadynamic-field/41346683#41346683

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I found the result as follows:

```
@Repository
public class GoleadorRepository {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public GoleadorRepository(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    public List<Goleador> list() {
        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                unwind("jogadoresGols"),
                group("jogadoresGols.jogador.nome").sum("jogadoresGols.numeroGols").as("totalGols"),
                project("totalGols").and("jogador").previousOperation(),
                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "totalGols")
        ), Partida.class, Goleador.class).getMappedResults();
    }

}
```

Below the grouping classes:

```
@Document
public class Partida {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String adversario;

    private LocalDate dataRealizacao;

    private Integer golsPro;

    private Integer golsContra;

    private Set<JogadorGols> jogadoresGols;

    //Getter e Setters omitidos

}

public class Goleador {

    private String jogador;

    private Integer totalGols;

    //Getters e Setters omitidos
}
```